# How to pass created_at from Rails via Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

My model is called Reports. I have an Ajax call, which is set to 
`@reports = Report.all`.

Report.all contains usual to Rails fields like created_at and updated_at.

Now, I'd like to show them on the page, but for some reason, JSON data passed to a page does not contain those fields. Is this some kind of Ruby security settings?

I'm curious how to enable them and via what mechanism JSON load has URL field which is not a part of a model?

UPD. 
Contoller code is

```
#GET /reports
#GET /reports.json
def index
   @reports = Report.all
end
```

When I print out Report.all in rails console, it contains `created_at` field. When I curl this controller via 0.0.0.0:3000/report.json , there are no created_at and updated_at fileds.

Comment: Can you post the view where you are trying to show `created_at`?

Comment: Please post some sample of code you are using

Comment: Hi ror, you will need to provide your code from the controller

Comment: if my answer didn't work, just let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the Rails generator will generate a jbuilder view file for the index:

```
$ rails generate scaffold Report ...
```

will give you:

```
# app/views/reports/index.json.jbuilder
json.array!(@reports) do |report|
  json.extract! report, :id, :some_other_attributes, ...
  json.url report_url(report, format: :json)
end
```

The `extract!` method will only output the attributes mentioned explicitly in its parameters. If you want to output `created_at` and `updated_at` in your json index, just add them to the method's parameters list:

```
  json.extract! report, :id, ..., :created_at, :updated_at
```

Comment: This! Thanks mate, you rock!